# Ошибка #1064 в работе с mysql запросом в планировщике событий

Tags: mysql

> Ответ MySQL: #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MariaDB на предмет корректного синтаксиса около `` 'UPDATE `credit_cards` SET `dolg` = `dolg` + (`dolg` / 100 * 28)' `` на строке 7

```
SELECT @id = (SELECT id FROM `credit_cards` WHERE dolg > 0),
@name = (SELECT name FROM `users` WHERE id = @id),
@names = (SELECT names FROM `users` WHERE id = @id),
@nameo = (SELECT nameo FROM `users` WHERE id = @id),
@bill = (SELECT bill FROM `credit_cards` WHERE id = @id),
@dolg = (SELECT dolg FROM `credit_cards` WHERE id = @id);
UPDATE `credit_cards` SET `dolg` = `dolg` + (`dolg` / 100 * 28)
```

Comment: то что у вас написано - это два запроса. возможно, в этом и пробема

Comment: А первый запрос способен дать правильный результат разве что случайно...